# How do I fire the cannon in 3-2 towards the right side?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

In Cyberspace Level 3-2 there is a launcher cannon with two trails of rings. Unlike the other cannons in the level, this one doesn't display a button prompt when I enter it. It either shoots me upwards if I press a button or drops me down if I let the timer run out. However, [videos of the stage](https://youtu.be/DjhYlty6zZQ?t=23) show the cannon can be fired towards the right.

How do I get the cannon in 3-2 to shoot me sideways towards the right?

[image: Cannon in 3-2 aimed to the right]
<sub>Screenshot from [Stickman Guides - Sonic Frontiers - Cyberspace Level 3-2](https://youtu.be/DjhYlty6zZQ?t=23)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Cannons that don't have a listed prompt will fire you to the right if you press the attack button (X/Circle) or up if you press the jump button (A/X).  Controls listed are Xbox/Playstation.